How to have different sessions for different realms in Authorization Server?
I am trying to create an authorization server for learning purpose. The auth servers supports multiple realms. I want to know what is the best way to store the logged in user's information in session for differnt realms. For different realms, I am not using different subdomains, but different paths. Like, the Client application will redirect the user to http://localhost:9000/realms/first-realm/auth url, where first-realm is id of the realm. Below is the code (see the comment in code):
@Controller
@RequestMapping("realms/{realmId}/auth")
public class AuthorizationController {
@GetMapping
  public String handleAuthRequest(
      @PathVariable("realmId") String realmId,
      @RequestParam Map<String, String> query,
      Model model
  ) {
    AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(
        realmId,
        query.get("client_id"),
        query.get("redirect_uri"),
        query.get("response_type"),
        query.get("scope"),
        query.get("state")
    );
    logger.info("Authorization request: {}", authRequest);
    Realm realm = this.authorizationService.verifyAuthRequest(authRequest);
    String authRequestId = this.authorizationService.getAuthRequestId (authRequest);
    // Here I want to know if user already has an active session
    // with authorization server for given realmId or not
    String authActionURI = "/realms/" + realmId + "/auth/" + authRequestId + "/login";
    model.addAttribute("realm", realm);
    model.addAttribute("authActionURI", authActionURI);
    return "user-login";
  }
}

The solution I can think of is storing information for different realms using a single cookie / session. And based on the realmId, we can determine if the user is logged in or not.
